# Data loader error

Tags: data-loader

I have installed data loader. When I open the data loader getting error for configure file. How can I resolve this error. Please find attachment of image file. Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: It seems like the config.properties File is missing in the directory. It's a simple properties file. Please check in the folder name as mentioned in the error.

Comment: Please try to re-install it again.

Comment: @sunny it's working fine..